# issue while installing jaybizzle/laravel-crawler-detect

Tags: php, laravel

getting this error while installing
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- laravel/sail is locked to version v1.25.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- laravel/sail v1.25.0 requires php ^8.0 -> your php version (7.4.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
- psr/log 2.0.0 requires php >=8.0.0 -> your php version (7.4.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v8.83.27 requires psr/log ^1.0|^2.0 -> satisfiable by psr/log[2.0.0].
- laravel/framework is locked to version v8.83.27 and an update of this package was not requested.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require jaybizzle/crawler-detect:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require jaybizzle/crawler-detect:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

downgraded the version of laravel/sail but still get error
enerating optimized autoload files

In ClassMapGenerator.php line 129:

Could not scan for classes inside "D:\chatsite\vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [...]

please help me out with this as my site is live i cant upgrade php version as it might affect other dependencies